# Social media icons are not aligning

Tags: html, css

Making a footer with social media icons and the images are entered but one is oddly higher than the other. Not sure how to fix it :(. Here is my html code:

```
<div class="socials">
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Geekyourselfout/"><img src="facebook-box-fill.png" alt="Facebook"</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/geekyourselfout/"><img src="instagram-fill.png" alt="Instagram"</a></li>
</div>
```

And the external CSS code:

```
.socials  {
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; 
 }
.socials img  {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  }
.socials a  {
  text-decoration: none;
  }
.socials li {
  list-style-type: none;
  }
.socials a:hover {
  color: red;
  }
```

[Here's a picture of how it looks rn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXylK.png)
All advice and help will be appreciated, thanks in advance :).

Comment: It works aligned in my editor after code formatting. So try that with correct syntax and edit your typo problems.

Comment: I should mention for context: I use TextEdit since I'm a Mac user, so it auto-capitalizes the first letter of each line of code. I'll update on if editing all the code to be lower-case fixes my issue. Damn I feel embarrassed it was typos being the first issue, but at least another pair of eyes caught it :).

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because of your typos. "align-items;" "items:","text-decorations","text-decoration"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there might be some typos in your css. `Align-items; center;` should be: `align-items: center;`. Also Text-decorations is not a css property, it's `text-decoration`.

Try that out. (FYI, it's not generally common to capitalize css properties, I'd change those all to lowercase.)

Answer (score 0):

```
.socials {
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
   }
```

Try this css snippet and make the following changes. You had given semicolon in align-items. In addition, typo error is there so write down in small-case.

Comment: thanks, it has gotten my icons to align better but there's still that noticeable placement difference where the Facebook icon is a bit higher than the Instagram icon. I think it may be an issue with my footer in general.